# SwiftUI ScrollView, GeometryReader and Button = Weird Behaviour

Tags: ios, swiftui, ipados, geometryreader

For the past 2 hours, I have been trying to get a ScrollView of buttons to work, more specifically ScrollView of buttons that uses GeometryReader to determine its size. Additionally, all this is placed within a NavigationView.

There was weird behaviour like the buttons not performing its action, not registering the tap, and when placed in HStack within a VStack for grid-like structure, I could only tap the first row of buttons with the intended effects, the other buttons were all unresponsive. How do I structure all of these views properly?

Answer (score 2):

The code below worked for me:

```
    var body : some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                GeometryReader{ geometry in
                    ScrollView {
                      // This is just how i'm setting up my buttons
                        VStack {
                            ForEach(0 ..< 2, id: \.self) { row in
                                HStack {
                                    ForEach(0 ..< 2, id: \.self) { column in
                                        TestButton()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
```

Note that the ScrollView has to be nested *within* the GeometryReader, if not there would be weird behavior (in my case, I could only tap the first line of buttons with the intended effects). Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Your code does not match the comment. Can you fix the code or the comment?  Your GeometryReader is NOT nested within the ScrollView in the above code.

Comment: No worries, thanks for updating. I noticed similar weird behaviour with buttons and scrollviews too.